# Trouble authenticating to facebook chat on Blackberry

Tags: facebook, blackberry, java-me, xmpp

I am currently working on a blackberry app that needs to connect to facebook chat. I am attempting to use the XMPP/Jabber interface. I can get the challenge from the server, however when I send my response I get a "not authorized" failure. My response is structured in this way:

> api_key=[my api key]&call_id=[time in millis]&method=auth.xmpp_login&nonce=[nonce from challenge]&session_key=[explained below]&v=1.0&sig=[calculated as shown below]

For the session key, I send the user a browserfield to Facebook's site. It returns an access token in the form `AAA...|BBB...|CCC...` where `BBB...` is the session key

The sig is calculated by taking the following string, md5ing it, and then converting the bytes to a hexadecimal string:

> api_key=[my api key]call_id=[time in millis]method=auth.xmpp_loginnonce=[nonce from challenge]session_key=[explained above]v=1.0[secret key appended here]

from there I base64 encode the response, and send:
    `<response xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>[Base64EncodedResponse]</response>`

Facebook's response is consistently a not-authorized error, with no adidtional explanation. Is there something that is missing or something? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. The problem was, it wants the session secret, not the app secret. So the secret key appended at the end of the signature is obtained from calling auth.promoteSession, not from the App Secret on the website.